# Boolean values of PHP strings

Tags: php, casting, weak-typing

I am trying to understand the truthiness of strings in PHP. I thought it might be like other scripting language like Javascript or Python.

```
> var_dump((bool)"");
bool(false);

> var_dump((bool)"hello");
bool(true);
```

Okay, makes sense.

Then  I tried

```
> var_dump((bool)"0");
bool(false);
```

Really? That's weird. I guess PHP tries to parse the string as a number first. So this should also be `false`

```
> var_dump((bool)"00");
bool(true);
```

Huh?!? I am really confused, and would like to know what makes a string truthy or not.

I haven't been able to find anything so far.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#112190

Answer (score 2):

See the docs for [converting to boolean](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting):

> When converting to boolean, the following values are considered
>   FALSE:
>
> ```
> the boolean FALSE itself
> the integer 0 (zero)
> the float 0.0 (zero)
> the empty string, and the string "0"
> an array with zero elements
> an object with zero member variables (PHP 4 only)
> the special type NULL (including unset variables)
> SimpleXML objects created from empty tags
> ```
>
> Every other value is considered TRUE (including any resource).

Answer (score 1):

From [**booleans php documentation**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php)

> When converting to boolean, the following values are considered FALSE:
>
> the boolean FALSE itself
> the integer 0 (zero)
> the float 0.0 (zero)
> the empty string, and the string "0"
> an array with zero elements
> an object with zero member variables (PHP 4 only)
> the special type NULL (including unset variables)
> SimpleXML objects created from empty tags

So yes, your example have sense, `0` is a boolean false while `00` is a string and is true